# Is there a way to clear one line of session storage?

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I am trying to clear one line of session storage, therefore

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```

doesn't work. I tried using

```
.setItem()
```

as well but that isn't really what I am looking for because I want to clear it not set it to anything.

Comment: it's an object, so simply use delete: `delete sessionStorage.myUnwantedValue;` personally, i don't see why coders prefer methodical access to local/sessionStroage; they went out of their way to give us a nice plain-object API and people still use methods instead of assignment, Object.keys, delete, etc. maybe they like parens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is sessionStorage.removeItem()

Comment: MDN is your friend.  Also, the autocompletion in Chrome's devtools, along with a few educated guesses about how the function you're looking for might begin..  :)